# how to get another model property in the view in the asp-for field

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, view, model

How to get the coursename text box value in the asp-for in the view. course is different model which is linke with foreign key. im getting compiling error while im using asp-for="CourseName"

```
public partial class Student
{
    public int StdId { get; set; }
    public string? StdName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<StudentCourse> StudentCourses { get; } = new List<StudentCourse>();
}

public partial class StudentCourse
{
    public int StdId { get; set; }
    public int CourseId { get; set; }
    public string CourseName { get; set; }
    public virtual Student? StdId { get; set; }
 }
view
<input type="text" class="form-control" asp-for="CourseName" id="CourseName" name="CourseName">

controller
public IActionResult Save(IFormCollection formdata)
{
var coursedetails = formdata["CourseName"];
}
```

```
public partial class Student
{
    public int StdId { get; set; }
    public string? StdName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<StudentCourse> StudentCourses { get; } = new List<StudentCourse>();
}

public partial class StudentCourse
{
    public int StdId { get; set; }
    public int CourseId { get; set; }
public string CourseName { get; set; }
    public virtual Student? StdId { get; set; }
 }
view
<input type="text" class="form-control" asp-for="CourseName" id="CourseName" name="CourseName">

controller
public IActionResult Save(IFormCollection formdata)
{
var coursedetails = formdata["CourseName"];
}
```

Comment: Your **CourseName** property is in **StudentCourses** Collection. *asp-for* is not working with collection, it works with single item.  
for example:
 

    <input type="text" class="form-control" asp-for="@StudentCourses.FirstOrDefualt().CourseName" id="CourseName" name="CourseName">

Answer (score 0):

> How to get the coursename text box value in the asp-for in the view.
> course is different model which is linke with foreign key. im getting
> compiling error while im using asp-for="CourseName"

You are getting right error because your CourseName is a type of collection so either you would need to define index of course which you want to display or need to loop over your course list.However, based on your scenario and description you would either want to display course list as dropdown or textbox both can be implemented.

Let's have a look in action:

Course List As TextBox:

Model:

```
public partial class StudentClass
    {
        public int StdId { get; set; }
        public string? StdName { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<StudentCourse> StudentCourses { get; set; } = new List<StudentCourse>();
    }
```

Controller Action To Load View:

```
public IActionResult LoadStudentAndCourseWithList()
        {
            var courseList = new List<StudentCourse>()
            {
                new StudentCourse(){ CourseId =301,CourseName = "C#.NET"},
                new StudentCourse(){ CourseId =302,CourseName = "SQL"}
            };

            var studentClass =new StudentClass();
            studentClass.StudentCourses = courseList;
            return View(studentClass);
        }
```

View Cshtml:

```
@model YourProject.Model.StudentClass
<form method="post" action="Save">
    <div class="mb-3">
        <label asp-for="StdName" class="control-label"></label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" asp-for="StdName">
    </div>
   @foreach (var item in Model.StudentCourses)
    {
        <input type="text" class="form-control" asp-for="@item.CourseName">
    }
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Contoller Action On Submit:

```
public IActionResult Save(IFormCollection formdata)
        {
            var dynamicFormDataDictionary = new Dictionary<string, object>();

            foreach (var item in formdata)
            {

                dynamicFormDataDictionary.Add(item.Key, item.Value);
               
            }


            return Ok();
        }
```

Output:

[image]

[image]